# CSS height doesn't work perfectly in firefox

Tags: php, html, css

```
div.aboutstandard ul.aboutlist li {
    float: left;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 280px;
}

div.aboutstandard ul.aboutlist li {
float: left;
padding-left: 10px;
padding-right: 10px;
width: 300px;
height: 280px;
}
```

When i am setting this dimensions for the height, it works perfectly in chrome and internet explorer, but in firefox it takes different dimensions. the text goes under the next image in firefox.

php code:

```
<ul class="aboutlist1">
         <li>
            <img class="aboutimg" src="images1.jpg" alt="<? $lang->text('ABOUT1'); ?>"/>

            <h1><? $lang->text('ABOUT1'); ?></h1>

            <p class="abouttext"><? $lang->text('ABOUT_TEXT1'); ?></p>
        </li>

        <li>
            <img class="aboutimg" src="images2.jpg" alt="<? $lang->text('ABOUT2'); ?>"/>

            <h1><? $lang->text('ABOUT2'); ?></h1>

            <p class="abouttext"><? $lang->text('ABOUT_TEXT2'); ?></p>
        </li>
       </ul>
<ul class="aboutlist">
        <li>
            <img class="aboutimg" src="image3.jpg" alt="<? $lang->text('ABOUT3'); ?>"/>

             <h1><? $lang->text('ABOUT3'); ?></h1>

            <p class="abouttext"><? $lang->text('ABOUT_TEXT3'); ?></p>
        </li>

        <li>
            <img class="aboutimg" src="image4.jpg" alt="<? $lang->text('ABOUT4'); ?>"/>

            <h1><? $lang->text('ABOUT4'); ?></h1>

            <p class="abouttext"><? $lang->text('ABOUT_TEXT4'); ?></p>
        </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: with a demo would be more easy.

Comment: Testing on my local it outputs the same in ff & chrome. What version of ff are you testing in? At the least a screenshot of what's happening would be useful

Comment: i didn't know whats the problem, it didnt work for me in firefox 10.0.4 and it worked fine in 10.0.2

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use

```
if(strlen(strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"Firefox")) > 0 ){
//Adjusted css for firefox here
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Provide code so that i can see through it or use `height: 280px !important;` or use prefix for firefox browser support